# How to Pass data from different excel sheet having different data into a Test in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

My initial requirement is ,i have two excel sheets

1 st sheet contains FirstName,Last Name
2 nd sheet contains Company ,Email

i have to combine the two sheets data and pass it to test and in test it should take

First Set .... FirstName,LastName,Company,Email.
Second Set..   FirstName,LastName,Company,Email..

till data exists in the excel sheet..
problem here is while passing the parameters i have to pass four parameters but in excel sheet 2 parameters...

Help is required......

===================================================================================================

public Object[][] dataDetails() throws BiffException, IOException{

```
    String pathofExcel="D:\\Test-Excel3.xls";
    String sheetName="test";

    Generics gen=new Generics();
    String employeeDetails[][]=gen.excelRead(pathofExcel, sheetName);


    return employeeDetails;
}

public Object[][] dataDetails2() throws BiffException, IOException{

    String pathofExcel="D:\\Test-Excel4.xls";
    String sheetName="test";

                 Generics gen=new Generics();
    String employeeDetailss[][]=gen.excelRead(pathofExcel, sheetName);

    return employeeDetailss;
}

      @DataProvider(name="enterformDetails")
public Object[][] dp() throws BiffException, IOException {
      List<Object[]> result = Lists.newArrayList();
      result.addAll(Arrays.asList(dataDetails()));
      result.addAll(Arrays.asList(dataDetails2()));
      return result.toArray(new Object[result.size()][]);
    }



@Test(dataProvider="enterformDetails")  
public  void employDetails(String FName,String LastName,String Comp,String Email){
    EmpDetails emp=new EmpDetails();
    emp.enterDetails(FName, LastName, Comp,Email);

  }
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: how are u associating which firstname lastname should be combined with which email company??

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a Dataprovider that would read these 2 files and return an iterator combining the values from both the files.

```
 @DataProvider
    public CSVIterator1 genericDataProvider(){

    File input1 = new File("c:\\file1.csv");
    File input2 = new File("c:\\file2.csv");

    return new CSVIterator1(input1,input2);


}




@Test(dataProvider ="genericDataProvider")
public void test1(String s1 , String s2, String i1, String i2){



}
```

And you implement Iterator interface for our need. This is a CSV iterator. you can implement an excel iterator. You just get the idea.

```
   public class CSVIterator1 implements Iterator{

String line1;
String line2;
BufferedReader rdr1;
BufferedReader rdr2;

CSVIterator1(File input1 ,File input2){

    try {
         rdr1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input1));
         rdr2 =new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input2));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {

    try {
        if((line1 = rdr1.readLine()) != null && (line2 = rdr2.readLine()) != null){
            return true;
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}



@Override
public void remove() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public Object next() {

    if(line1 !=null && line2 !=null){

        return genParams(line1,line2);

    }

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}



public Object[] genParams(String line1 , String line2){

    String combined = line1+","+line2;


    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(combined, ",");
    Object[] result = new Object[st.countTokens()];
    int i=0;
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){

        result[i] = st.nextElement();
        i++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest, create a Map from xls files and depending upon input use this map to get the data using map key. It will help you a lot as only before suite you create a map and use this map anywhere in your script. If you do this then you don't have to @DataProvider anywhere in script.

Steps: Create a map from xls
Read map values using key
Pass as a testdata to testcase.